# Where to start reading Berserk manga if I've seen the anime?

Tags: suggested-order, adaptation-comparison, berserk

Title basically says all. I've seen the anime and want to start the manga (but skip over the common part). From where should I start?

Comment: I would think this would be completely dependent on whether the OP saw the entire run of the anime, or just a portion of it, even assuming that this particular manga and anime can be synced up. (unless it really does qualify as general reference). Since I believe it would be too broad if reopened, and the OP hasn't been seen for 1.5 years at this point, voting to leave closed.

Answer (score 1):

[wikipedia entry for berserk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berserk_%28manga%29#Anime)

> The first thirteen volumes of the manga are covered, including the first arc (Black Swordsman). Though the manga storyline remains largely intact, many changes were made with the modification or elimination of characters, some of the series' most violent and brutal scenes, and material that would have extended the storyline beyond the planned run of the anime series. Themes of friendship and ambition are more developed and emphasized than those of causality and the supernatural, all of which were made with the approval of series creator Kentarō Miura.

That being said you might still want to read said first 13 volumes, there are many scenes skipped in the anime.